# How can a color blindness simulation in FFmpeg be done?

Tags: ffmpeg, video, colors, video-editing

How a can color blindness simulation in FFmpeg be done?

I am asking this question because I want to make a YouTube video with simulated color blindness.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use LUT for simulate different types of colour blindness. You can get these LUTs from [here](http://blog.eppz.eu/design-color-blind-users/) for example. And then apply one of them to specific video file adding `lut3d` filter:

```
ffmpeg -i "Input1.mov" -vf lut3d="ARRIP3D65PQ108-33.cube" ....
```